# What's the domain name of my node.js server?

Tags: node.js, json, express, flutter, server

I am trying to fetch data from the server to my flutter app. This is my server side code in Node.js:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
app.use(express.json());
const getres='himu you got the request';
app.post('/post',async(req,res,next)=>{
const name= req.body.name;
console.log(name);
next();
}
);

app.get('/get',async(req,res,next)=>{
res.end('hello world');
res.json('hey from nodejs');
next();
}
);

app.listen(3000);
```

This is my flutter code where I am trying to fetch a string from the server but the string is returning null when I am printing in the flutter console.I am confused what should be my `DOMAIN`.

```
const PROTOCOL = "http";
const DOMAIN = "localhost:3000";

Future<RequestResult> http_get(String route, [dynamic data]) async
{
  var dataStr = jsonEncode(data);
  var url = "$PROTOCOL://$DOMAIN/$route?data=$dataStr";
  var result = await http.get(url);
  return RequestResult(true, jsonDecode(result.body));
}
```

Here I am trying to print the data

```
 Future<void> getdata() async {
   var result= await http_get('get');
   print(result.data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the server is it on your local machine on which your flutter is also running

if yes, then your domain is localhost:3000

else domain name is IP of the server where your Node code is hosted and running, (if you have DNS masked with IP, you can you use something like http://myserver.com, myserver is the domain name you masked hypothetically)

if your flutter app is running on mobile device and nodeJs on the local machine, you will need to be on the same network with your machine to access localhost:3000

Comment: I'm using my mobile phone's hotspot to connect to the internet where the server is running and the flutter app is running on mobile too.

Comment: where is your node.js server running?

Comment: it's working now,I just copied the IPv4 address of my connection and used it as the domain name. Thanks for your well explained answer though.

Comment: if it's on your local machine, find the IP address of the system (ipconfig gives on windows), google it for your OS, in Flutter localhost will point to your mobile devices localhost which is not your server localhost, You will need to use the IP address of the machine

Answer (score 0):

As seen, there is no problem with domain, try removing the query parameter in the url variable

```
const PROTOCOL = "http";
const DOMAIN = "localhost:3000";

Future<RequestResult> http_get(String route, [dynamic data]) async
{
  var dataStr = jsonEncode(data);
  var url = "$PROTOCOL://$DOMAIN/$route?data=$dataStr";
  var result = await http.get(url);
  return RequestResult(true, jsonDecode(result.body));
}
```

Here your query parameter `?data=$dataStr` is not availabe as you have only set the routes not the queries in the backend. 
You can send your get request to `/get` route